# Where to ask for a fabrics enhancement ? Report a bug?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-fabric

I wanna report a bug to Fabrics about their gradle android plugin. But I can't find any place to do so. There is no issue tracker and I should use their mail or stack over flow to submit a report ?

(The bug is that the gradle task for generating fabric resources is not cacheable and breaks chaching of resource tasks).

Comment: Can you send an email to support@fabric.io with details?

Comment: Amazing that this glorious question got a negative score.

Comment: thx @alexizamerican

Comment: I've up-voted this question since it is a valid question. Really need to impose a requirement that voting down require at least a reason for it. Anonymous down-voting simply encourages trolls who add nothing to the conversation.